# Quotient Construction of a Power Set, equivalence relations, and symmetric difference.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

Fixing $N \in P(X)$ (the power set of X), we say that $A,B \in P(X)$ $agree \ away \ from \ N$ if $A - N = B - N$.

I have to show that $A \sim A', B \sim B'$ implies that $(A \Delta B) \sim (A' \Delta B')$, where $A \Delta B$ is defined as $(A - B) \cup (B - A)$. I am unsure how to begin this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here, does $A \sim A'$ mean that $A$ and $A'$ *agree away from* our fixed $N$?

Comment: Indeed, yes it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by writing
$$ \begin{align} (A \Delta B) - N&= ((A - B)\cup (B - A)) - N \\
&= ((A - B)-N) \cup ((B - A)-N) \\
                                        &= ((A-N)-(B-N)) \cup ((B-N)-(A-N)) \end{align}$$
and similarly for $(A' \Delta B') - N$ (of course, you should check why each of the above steps is valid). Now use your assumption to conclude that these sets are identical.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a sufficient hint as I have found a proof.